# Java InvocationTargetException while calling private method

Tags: java, reflection

I have a private method with such a signature:

`private void compressFilesForSend(List<File> files, File archiveFile)`

and I want to invoke it in a test through reflection

```
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[2];
        parameterTypes[0] = java.util.List.class;
        parameterTypes[1] = java.io.File.class;

        Method method = SendDB.class.getDeclaredMethod("compressFilesForSend",parameterTypes);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(files, archiveFile);
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.m1_mm.tools.SendDB.compressFilesForSend(java.util.ArrayList, java.io.File)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at com.m1_mm.tools.SendDBTest.compressFilesForSendTest1(SendDBTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
```

How can this method be invoked?

Comment: The title says `InvocationTargetException` and the stack trace says `NoSuchMethodException`. Which is it?

Comment: what is the declared type of `files` ?? List or ArrayList ?

Comment: files type is ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

You've got the signature of `Method.invoke` wrong. You need to pass the *instance* that you want to invoke the method on, and then the parameters.

What you've done is to tell it to invoke the method on `files`, passing `archiveFile` as an argument; in other words, you're doing

```
files.compressFilesForSend(archiveFile);
```

but treating `files` as an instance of `SendDB`.

You need to work out which instance of `SendDB` you want to invoke the method on, and pass that as a first argument:

```
method.invoke(mySendDbInstance, files, archiveFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass the `files` parameter witch is an `ArrayList` but the method signature says that you expect a `List` parameter.

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>;    //it's ok
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>;    //it's not ok
```